# Use previous query result in a query

Tags: oracle

I'm building a football database. I store data about the position, points, etc of different teams in the past years.

I'm trying to write a query which gets all the teams which have ascended and then descended again. In order to do that, I've the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT team
    FROM Result
    WHERE number=42 AND 
        situation='ASCENT'
INTERSECT SELECT DISTINCT team
    FROM Result
    WHERE number=38 
        AND situation='DESCENT' 
        AND league='Premier league';
```

The key is that I need to express "temporality"; the year of the ascend has to be previous than the the year of the descend. In my `Result` table I've a `year` field, which I could use in order to compare the temporal order, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the *Result* table to itself like this:

```
SELECT
  team
FROM
  Result A
  JOIN Result D ON D.team = A.team AND A.year < D.year
WHERE
  A.number=42
  AND
  A.situation='ASCENT'
  AND
  D.number=38
  AND
  D.situation='DESCENT'
  AND
  D.league='Premier league'
```